# Struggle to get the same ViewModel instance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I'm not sure if I understand `ViewModel` architecture correctly in Android. I suppose ViewModel lifecycle is tie to the activity so we are expecting the same instance and it doesn't matter if we are passing the activity or fragment context to `ViewModelProvider`?

Anyway, here's my ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var teamName: String = "Warriors";
}
```

Here's my Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.teamName = "Cavaliers";
        Log.d("YouQi", "activity viewModel.teamName: ${viewModel.teamName}");

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly here's my Fragment:

```
class MainFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        Log.d("YouQi", "fragment viewModel.teamName: ${viewModel.teamName}");
    }

}
```

I'm getting the below output in Logcat:

```
2018-06-03 16:06:24.591 31124-31124/com.axzae.zapkotlin D/YouQi: activity viewModel.teamName: Cavaliers
2018-06-03 16:06:24.652 31124-31124/com.axzae.zapkotlin D/YouQi: fragment viewModel.teamName: Warriors
```

It shows the value did not update to Cavaliers. am I using ViewModel wrongly and should be using Dagger to achieve singleton?

Comment: I'm like you just started learning android architecture components, and I noted that in examples they usually use activity's context (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.java, look at `onCreateView` and https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksActivity.java, `obtainViewModel`)

Comment: On the other hand your code indeed looks like you want different view models - one for activity and one for fragment because of the way you're requesting them (otherwise it seems logic to request view model for activity only in both cases). Any way let's wait for someone with more experience to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does matter what `ViewModelProvider` are you using - from activity or from fragment. Please try to use `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())` for fragment.

That's actually very handy - you can keep fragment-related model and more general activity-bound model separately.

Comment: thanks! the reason I avoided using `activity` context earlier in fragment is because kotlin is complaining activity can be potentially a null object . I have to define it as `viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(MainViewModel::class.java)` instead. is this expected?

Comment: Yes... you can use `requireActivity()` method which returns Not-null, or crash if you use it at not appropriate moment

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to use Dependency injection to achieve singleton in ViewModel. You can pass the activity context to the ViewModel like this:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(MainViewModel::class.java)// by this you will get the same value of teamName as your activity
```